# How to update work item state after a release

Tags: azure-devops

We have multiple release pipelines (Dev, QA, etc.).  After a given release, we want to update the State for each work item associated with the release.  I understand that can cause problems if we manually re-release, or re-build. I see third party marketplace extensions that could do it, but is there a way to do it from something built into DevOps pipelines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried every out-of-the-box feature I can find to accomplish this and found my way blocked.

It seems the options are: use the extensions others have written, write your own, or dive into the REST API.

We are currently using the [WorkItem Updater](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater) extension for production stages.

Comment: The great thing about extensions like the WorkItem Updater is that the source is available, so if you're concerned about security, you can review the source, scan it for vulnerabilities, etc... The extensibility of AzDO is one of its best features.

Comment: Off topic: your abbreviation of Azure DevOps (`AzDO`) is my favorite so far.

Comment: AzDO. I think we should start a abbreviation contest for new vsts name. back on topic. I dont think reviewing extension code makes sense. it can change at any moment :) Rest Api seems like a good approach (its not like you have to DIVE, its literally 1 request)

Comment: As long as you have all the items. Are those available as a pre-defined variable?

Comment: @4c74356b41 a middle ground could be to fork an extension at a desired release and begin maintaining it yourself.